# Check internet connection issue

Tags: vb.net, forms, webclient

I'm making a simple application that require internet connection. But the problem is i'm getting a web exception when i start my application with my internet connection off. 

So i created a new form and added/set that form as the startup form of the application. 
I've added this code in that startup form's load:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'On form load i'm checking if the computer is connected to internet.
        If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then

            frmMain.Show() 'shows my application's main form
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            'if no connection then

            Dim result = MsgBox("Failed to establish connection!") ' show an error message
            If result = DialogResult.OK Then 'if button okay is pressed
                Application.Exit() 'exit the application!
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

But the problem is it's not doing anything at all. Still gives me an exception error!
What i'm trying to do is simple. 
1. On startup of my application, it checks whether internet connection is working or not.

2. If on check, internet connection not working: give an error messsage and if working, continues to the next form (main form of the app)

NOTE: The main form of my application does download a text file from a webserver using `webclient` method, and i'm getting an web exception error even when i use this new form as a startup. I did not add any more code to the new form, just the above code in the `Form_Load`

Any help on this?

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: You need to handle the error anyway in case the internet connection goes down between the check and the fetch.

Comment: Actually that function just checks if your computer is connected to a network not the internet.

Comment: @MarkHall it gives me this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The remote name could not be resolved: 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com'
`
dl.dropboxusercontent.com is where the file i'm downloading in the FrmMain(main form) is in. I don't understand why it gives me this error when i'm using a new form as startup to check internet connection before proceeding to main form. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Network.IsAvailable checks just the local network, not the Internet, instead use this method. However, the connection could still go down between this check and the moment in which you use it, so a try/catch around the download is a must.

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" _
        (ByRef lpdwFlags As Int32, ByVal dwReserved As Int32) As Boolean

Public Shared Function IsInternetAvailable() As Boolean
   Try
      Dim flags as Integer 
      return InternetGetConnectedState(flags, 0)
   Catch
      return False
   End Try
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(....)
    If Form1.IsInternetAvailable Then
      ......
```

However I am not sure if your problems are caused by the lack of Internet Connection availability. You should show the code where you try to download the file or, at least , report the exact error message

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how do i use that method? :|

I like a message box to appear if no connection and when there is connection proceed to the main form.

Comment: Paste the code in the same class of your form above and call it in place of My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable. (Answer updated)

Comment: Mucho gracias! :) That solved the question, works perfectly! :)